# Issue is header location sending a different URL

Tags: php, html, css

When the user deletes a project from my website a simple query deletes the attached records from the DB and the user is taken to the home page, which will show a bar at the top of the page "Project Deleted" I do this by having a GET 'err' in the URL, so when err isset the number next to it defines what alert should be shown at the top of the page.

The problem I am having is that the 4th alert is being shown instead of the 8th when this php script is run.

PHP:

```
if (mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM projects WHERE id='$del' AND user_id ='$user_id'")) {
        if (mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM refs WHERE project_id='$del' AND user_id ='$user_id'")) {
            setcookie("project_cookie", 0);
            header("Location: index.php/?del=8");
        }
    }
```

Alerts.php (attached at the top of the header file):

```
if (isset($_GET['err'])) {
    $err = $_GET['err'];
    $type = "err";

    if ($err == "1") { $alert = "Incorrect Email or Password"; }
    elseif ($err == "2") { $alert = "Email address already exists"; }
    elseif ($err == "3") { $alert = "All fields require values"; }
    elseif ($err == "4") { $alert = "Reference Deleted"; }
    elseif ($err == "5") { $alert = '<a href="http://bradleycousins.co.uk/?auth=signup">' . '<b>' . "Signup"  . '</b>' . '</a>'. " " . "to create and save references"; }
    elseif ($err == "6") { $alert = "You can only have 8 projects"; }
    elseif ($err == "7") { $alert = "Select a project on the left hand side first"; }
    elseif ($err == "8") { $alert = "You have deleted a project"; }

}
```

I have looked at this for a long while and have no idea why the 4th alert shows instead of the 8th when the PHP Delete script is run.

Answer (score 2):

Change,

```
header("Location: index.php/?del=8");
```

To,

```
header("Location: index.php/?err=8");
```

Because,

```
if (isset($_GET['err'])) {
```

Not,

```
if (isset($_GET['del'])) {
```

Comment: Simple mistake, thank you

Comment: I have now been banned because of the dislike on my question.